# Usage and Health Data Collection using SQL Authentication

Tags: authentication, sql-server, site-usage, powershell

I'm having an issue with trying to set my Usage and Health Data Collection to use SQL Authentication.  I have tried setting my database credentials to SQL Authentication using both Powershell and Central Administration.

Here is the Powershell command i've tried

> Set-SPUsageApplication –Identity “Usage and Health Data collection”
>   –DatabaseServer “192.168.0.79” -DatabaseName “WSS_Logging_New_DB”
>   -DatabaseUsername "sqlAdmin" -DatabasePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “password” –AsPlaintext –Force)

and Here is an image of my settings in Central Admin
[image]

My WSS_Logging_New_DB has no data in it except what is there when originally created but it seems the Timer Job is not using the correct credentials as seen in the logs below.

[image]

Here are 2 of the errors i continually get

> ConnectionString: 'Data Source=192.168.0.79;Initial
>   Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True;Application
>   Name=SharePoint[OWSTIMER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PslKl.jpg)[Master]'    Partition: NULL
>   ConnectionState: Closed ConnectionTimeout: 15

and

> SqlError: 'Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and
>   cannot be used with Windows authentication.'    Source: '.Net
>   SqlClient Data Provider' Number: 18452 State: 1 Class: 14 Procedure:
>   '' LineNumber: 65536 Server: '192.168.0.79'

Comment: Where you able to resolve this error?
We have discovered that it is the "Database Performance Metric Provider" timer job and we are now trying to set the permission "Grant View Server State" to the SQL account. Hope this works.